# MSQL + PHP - Check Query Issues

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a bit of an issue...

So what I'm trying to do is this:

I have a user table:

```
-------------------------
|   Table: userlist     |
-------------------------
| Id |  GuestOf | User  |
|-----------------------|
| 0  | System   | Bill  |
|-----------------------|
| 1  |   Bill   | Jason |
|-----------------------|
| 2  |  Jason   | Jack  |
|-----------------------|
| 3  |  Jason   | Jill  |
|-----------------------|
| 4  |   Jack   | Matt  |
|-----------------------|
| 5  |   Jill   |  Stu  |
|-----------------------|
| 6  |   Jack   | Gwen  |
|-----------------------|
| 7  |   Jill   | Frank |
|-----------------------|
```

Basically, Jason's guests are Jack and Jill, Jack's guests are Matt and Gwen, and Jill's Guests are Stu and Frank.

Now what I want to do is find out if Jason's guests both have their two guests.

But I can only check for this each time a new guest is added to the list. In this case, When Frank is added to the list by Jill.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
function countGuests($User) {
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`Id`) CntId FROM `userlist` WHERE `GuestOf` LIKE '$User'";

  $res = mysql_query($sql);

  $temp = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_BOTH);

  return $temp["CntId"];        
}

function checkCompletion($UserId) {
  $population = array();

  $sql = "SELECT `User` FROM `userlist` WHERE `GuestOf` LIKE '$UserId'";

  $res = mysql_query($sql);

  if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($temp = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
      $population[] = $temp["User"];      
    }

    $partialPop = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($populaton); ++$i) {
        $partialPop = $partialPop + countGuests($population[$i]);
    }
  }

  return $partialPop;
}
```

Which should give me the result: 7 (Jason, Jack, Jill, Matt, Gwen, Stu, Frank)

However, I get the result: 0. What's wrong with my query?

I would appreciate any help/corrections...

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered rebuild of your database? strange method for relations

Comment: You should create a table with the relation of the guests. In this basic example there is no much difference, but when you start adding information to your tables (gender, address, dates, etc) this issue is important.

Comment: AFAIK, this table is hierarchical. Check out this id = 0 (system): is the root of all the structure. You are missing important information.
The requested information is to retrieve the lists of all guests in the system??? if this is the question, you should start by thinking on a recursive funcion.

Comment: @RaulLuna: I want to know whether or not Jason's Guests (Jack and Jill) each have 2 guests. When Bill came in, there were no other people so he is the guest of System.

Comment: @Strawberry: No, the statement is correct. Frank is the user, and he is a guest of Jill. So when Frank is entered to the list as a Guest of Jill...

Comment: @JonDavis you should hold names in one table and create relations in other

Comment: @Daimos: So what I want to achieve is impossible given the current structure?

Comment: @Strawberry, yes, I see your point. However, I am explaining to you that it isn't. I will edit the column header so it makes more sense to you but my problem still exists...

Comment: @Strawberry: I seriously don't know if you're trying to help or troll on this. You didn't understand the table names, I explained it. You didn't like my explanation, I edited the Column Name. And still you have something to say but not really useful to help me with my issue...

Comment: @JonDavis For consistency, why not rename the table `userlist`. Have fun.

Comment: @Strawberry: There you go. Happy now? Hopefully you can contribute something...

Comment: OK, why are we looking for Jason's guests - as opposed to anyone else's?

Comment: Jason is merely an example. The function checkCompletion should be able to check whether or not Jason and his 2 guests also have 2 guests each. But right now, it doesn't. Which is why I started this question...

Comment: But the trigger for 'checkcompletion' is an insert - which may complete someone's list - but it may not be Jason's, right?

Comment: Yes. Which is why checkCompletion starts from the bottom and then works its way up. Or at least that's what it's supposed to do. Like I explained below, when Frank gets inserted, I get Jill. Check if she has her 2 guests. Then check who invited her (Jason), check if he has 2 guests, now get the other guest (Jack) and see if he has 2 guests. If they all have their 2 guests each, I should get a value of 7. Which will signal completion of that group of people and guests. When the next person gets inserted, checkCompletion runs again for that insert...

Comment: Can Gwen, Matt, Frank, and Stu have guests?

Comment: @JonDavis its always possible, as you can see the answers. You can also keep those names inside xml, or plain text file and it will work. But mysql relations just can be created better. Good relations may make you work easier and faster.

Comment: @Daimos: Then perhaps a little help as none of the answers help me solve my issue...

Comment: I give you a hint before, other table for names, other for relations and "mysql relationships" related tutorials will be helpfull, if you try this way, and have some problems just ask

Comment: @Daimos: How does that help with my question of what is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following. I've changed the column/table names to ease conceptualisation...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS guestlist;

CREATE TABLE guestlist
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,user VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,guest VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(user,guest)
);

INSERT INTO guestlist VALUES
(1,'System','Bill'),
(2,'Bill','Jason'),
(3,'Jason','Jack'),
(4,'Jason','Jill'),
(5,'Jack','Matt'),
(6,'Jill','Stu'),
(7,'Jack','Gwen'),
(8,'Jill','Frank');

SELECT a.user
     , a.guest
     , GROUP_CONCAT(b.guest) guest_of_guest
     , COUNT(*) total 
  FROM guestlist a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN guestlist b 
    ON b.user = a.guest 
 WHERE a.user = 'Jason' 
 GROUP 
    BY user
     , guest;
+-------+-------+----------------+-------+
| user  | guest | guest_of_guest | total |
+-------+-------+----------------+-------+
| Jason | Jack  | Gwen,Matt      |     2 |
| Jason | Jill  | Frank,Stu      |     2 |
+-------+-------+----------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is that you have to traverse all the nodes in a hierarchical table, you should think in a recursive function instead of an iterative function.

The following is an outline of a function that retrieves the list of all the users (including system):

You have to call this function with an empty array, and I expect that the result is returned in the same array, but I'm not sure if it is the case in php....

```
function retrieveAllUsers($UserId, $population) {

  $sql = "SELECT `User` FROM `guestlist` WHERE `Guest` LIKE '$UserId'";

  $res = mysql_query($sql);

  if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    temp = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_BOTH);
    // traverse the array $temp
    // in every iteration....
       // push into $population the value $temp["User"];      
       retrieveAllUsers( $currentUser, $population ); 

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I do not want to traverse all the nodes in the table. I just want to know whether or not Jack has 2 guests and Jill has 2 guests. Basically, when Frank is added, since I know he's Jill's guest, check who guested Jill and then get the partner guest (Jack) and check if he as 2 guests as well...

Comment: @JonDavis Jill is definitely Frank's guest!